# Image extends beyond text column in reopen review queue

Tags: bug

I was working through the reopen vote queue, and came across [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/8619073). There are no images in the latest version of the question, but there was one in the previous revision. In the review queue, the image present in the prior revision overlaps the text of the latest version:

[image: Image Overlap 1]
[image: Image Overlap 2]

I am working in Windows 8.1 on Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m. Everything is displayed correctly if I visit the question and view the normal edit history.

Comment: reproed on Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome 43.0.2357.130 also this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/r0VXi.jpg hasn't got the bar across.